# Optimization - area and volume of a bowl-shaped can

Tags: calculus, optimization

I'm deciding to create a new can .

The picture below is my idea of design .

[image]

How do I find the

1. Amount of material used , (surface area only , ignore thickness)
2. Volume of the original can .

Amount of material used from the surface area , there is 2 circles (bigger Top and smaller bottom) . But I'm having problem on how to find the surface area of the curved sides as seen from the side view .

As for volume , I'm stuck too...

Any help would be appreciated! 
Anyway , it looks like a bowl

Comment: Since you're planning to go into business, you should know that you have to invest money to make money. I advise you to hire a mathematical consultant.

Comment: the total surface (bottom plus side) and the volume depend on the base radii as well as the side function (can be a line or a curve) you define...